# Create/Update multiple records with one request in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, post, promise, sails.js, waterline

I would like to know what is the best practice to create/update multiple records in one request. I know we can do this using Promise.all(). But what if I want to tell the client which records succeeded and which failed?

For example, the user post something like:

```
{
    departmentId: 1,
    students: [
                  {name: 'John', studentId: 123},
                  {name: 'Mike', studentId: 124},
              ]
}
```

And my current solution is:

StudentController:

```
var departmentId = req.param('departmentId');
var postStudents = req.param['students'];

var department;
var failedRecords = [];
Department.findOne()
    .then(function (_department) {
        department = _department;
        var students = [];
        while (postStudents.length) {
            var student = postStudents.pop();
            student.department = departmentId;
            var s = Student.create(s)
                        .then(function(s){return s;})
                        .catch(function(e){ failedRecords.push(student)}); // A closure problem happens here
            students.push(s);
        }
        return students;
    })
    .each(function (student) {
        department.students.add(student[0].id);
        return department.save().catch(function(e){/* log: add to department failed */});
    })
    .then(function () {
        return res.json({msg: "Success"});
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        return res.json(404, {err: "Fail", records: failedRecords});
    });
```

The code is ugly, and I have also omit code to solve the closure problem in the while loop. Plus, I don't know how to save to failedRecords in the 2nd catch.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to simply run the following to generate records for the students. See [waterline-orm/models/create](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/create) for more.

```
// create the students
var students = [{name: 'John', studentId: 123},{name: 'Mike', studentId: 124}];
Student.create(students).exec(function createCB(err, created){
  console.log('Created student with name ' + created[0].name);
  console.log('Created student with name ' + created[1].name);
  //Do other stuff here.
});
```

Comment: Note that under the hood, Sails may actually be sending each record as a separate query to the DB (at least, it certainly did before v1.0). If you're looking for performance, it's best to use `createEach`, as @D3skDev demonstrates in their answer.

Answer (score 3):

You need [createEach()](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/create-each)

this is code sample from my project.

> controllers\FilesController.js

```
module.exports = {
  upload: function (req, res) {

    req.file('files').upload({
        dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'Files')
      },
      function (err, files) {
        if (err) {
          return res.serverError(err);
        }

        var array = [];
        files.forEach(file => {
          data = {
            name: file.filename,
            size: file.size,
            md5: 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e',
            uploaded_by: req.user.id
          }

          array.push(data)

        });


        Files.createEach(array).fetch().exec(function (err, user) {
          if (err) return res.serverError(err);
          sails.log(user)
        })

        res.json({
          "Status": files.length + " file(s) uploaded successfully!",
          "Files": files,
        });

      })

  },

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess Sails use the Q library. If not, you can convert any promise to Q using `Q.()`.

So, instead of `Q.all()` method, have you seen `Q.allSettled()`?

Here is the difference from both methods ([from the Q library guide](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination)):

> The all function returns a promise for an array of values. When this promise is fulfilled, the array contains the fulfillment values of the original promises, in the same order as those promises. If one of the given promises is rejected, the returned promise is immediately rejected, not waiting for the rest of the batch. If you want to wait for all of the promises to either be fulfilled or rejected, you can use allSettled.

The `Q.allSettled()` will wait for all promises to complete, even if one or more are rejected, and return an array of objects like:
`{ state: "fulfilled", value: v } or { state: "rejected", reason: r }`

[API Reference - promise.allSettled()](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled)

I'm not sure if this is the best practice for inserting in a database, because maybe waterline has a batch insert mode. But I've already done in this way while posting to an API to insert records and worked fine for me.

Comment: sails.js uses bluebird, not Q.

Comment: Hi Tulio, that's exactly what I wanted. But I don't find this in Bluebird :-(

Comment: In bluebird, `.allSettled` is just called `.settle`

Comment: Yes, thanks. I've also figured out that I could track which promise fails using bind()